# binding second datagrid to selecteditem of first datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid. When a row is clicked upon the rowdetails are displayed. This works fine.

In the rowdetails there is a check box & if the user clicks this then another datagrid appears, again this works.

The problem is that when this additional datagrid appears there are column headers but you can't enter data, there is no row to enter data, why?

**XAML Code (some omitted to keep it short)**

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding HldLogEQCurr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedHldLogEq, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate1}"
                          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeaderCenter1}"                                            
                          RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row1}"
                          CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell1}"                                    
                          RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader1}"                              
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                           
                          Background="Silver" 
                          Margin="50,50,50,50"                              
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          RowHeaderWidth="30">

                        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid x:Name="RowDetailGrid"            
                                      Margin="5"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left">


                                            <DataGrid Grid.Row="2"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.NewSecurityList,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                                  
                                              RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"  
                                              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}" 
                                              RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeaderNested}"
                                              CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}" 
                                              Background="Silver"
                                              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                                              VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                                              CanUserAddRows="False"
                                              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                              Margin="50,5,5,0"
                                              Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkParent, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
                                              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ISIN" Binding="{Binding ISIN, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="75"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sedol" Binding="{Binding Sedol, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="75"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ticker" Binding="{Binding Ticker, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="75"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="200"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="FX" Binding="{Binding FX, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" MinWidth="75"/>
                                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                            </DataGrid>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Comment: there is CanUserAddRows="False": When this property is set to TRUE a blank row is displayed at the bottom of the DataGrid. A user can enter a new item into the blank row. Also, what type is NewSecurityList?

Comment: even when i can CanUserAddRows="True" it doesn't make any difference. Is the binding wrong? NewSecurityList is a list of type SecurityDescription

Comment: Does it display values correctly in additional DataGrid ?? Is it like it shows only text block and not textbox ?

Comment: sorry just found my mistake, I didn't have "RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" in my itemsource. Now I do its working